# How to disallow usages of "window.document.[anything]" and "document.[anything]" in eslint config?

Tags: configuration, eslint

I want to dissalow usages of window.document or document (where context is window) in my code.

But I want to leave possibility to disable this rule for a line by standard eslint comment.

I have found some similar questions on stackoverflow, but these questions haven't answers. Also I have not find any existing rule to do what I want.

These code snippets should cause eslint errors:

```
  const myVar = window.document.location
```

```
  const myVar = document.location
```

So, how can I configure eslint to solve my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the rule [no-restricted-properties](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-properties) to disallow usages of `window.document`, and the rule [no-restricted-globals](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-globals) to disallow `document`. Both rules require a custom configuration.

```
{
    "no-restricted-properties": [
        "error",
        {
            "object": "window",
            "property": "document"
        }
    ],
    "no-restricted-globals": [
        "error",
        "document"
    ]
}
```

[**Demo link**](https://eslint.org/demo#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiLyogZXNsaW50IG5vLXJlc3RyaWN0ZWQtcHJvcGVydGllczogW1wiZXJyb3JcIiwgeyBcIm9iamVjdFwiOiBcIndpbmRvd1wiLCBcInByb3BlcnR5XCI6IFwiZG9jdW1lbnRcIiB9XSAqL1xuLyogZXNsaW50IG5vLXJlc3RyaWN0ZWQtZ2xvYmFsczogW1wiZXJyb3JcIiwgXCJkb2N1bWVudFwiXSAqL1xuXG5jb25zdCBteVZhcjEgPSB3aW5kb3cuZG9jdW1lbnQubG9jYXRpb247XG5jb25zdCBteVZhcjIgPSBkb2N1bWVudC5sb2NhdGlvbjtcbiIsIm9wdGlvbnMiOnsicGFyc2VyT3B0aW9ucyI6eyJlY21hVmVyc2lvbiI6Niwic291cmNlVHlwZSI6InNjcmlwdCIsImVjbWFGZWF0dXJlcyI6e319LCJydWxlcyI6e30sImVudiI6e319fQ==)